# Simpler way to repeatedly read lines and invoke a program

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I'd like to repeatedly read a line and invoke a program with the line as the argument—in effect, making a non-interactive program interactive.

Is there a simpler or shorter way than this?

```
while read line; do
  cowsay $line
done
```

Comment: From which source do you read?

Comment: It is already pretty simple

Comment: @Cyrus standard input

Comment: @anubhava Agreed. Can it be simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
xargs -d '\n' -n 1 cowsay
```

Comment: Was going to suggest same to OP, +1

Comment: You need `-n 1` if you want to avoid `-I {}`. They serve the same purpose. Telling `xargs` to run the command once-per-line.

Comment: You can save 2 characters: `xargs -I % cowsay %`

Comment: @EtanReisner, `-n 1` tells xargs to run the command once per _argument_, not once per line.

Comment: You have to use `-d '\n' -n 1`. `-I {}` doesn't work because it interprets quotes

Comment: But the non `-I {}` versions also depend on the application reading all arguments if the line contains spaces. `-I {}` properly quotes the line as one argument. Try `xargs -I {} printf '[%s]\n' {}` versus `xargs -L 1 printf '[%s]\n'` with `foo bar` and `"foo bar"` as input. And all of these let `xargs` remove quotes from the input.

Comment: `-L 1` also interprets quotes. If you input `I'm a cow`, you get "xargs: unmatched single quote;"

Comment: @EtanReisner `-L 1` is already broken in other ways. Try it with `-d '\n' -n 1`

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah, `-d '\n' -n 1` appears to be the only way (short of using `-0` which can make normal input hard).

Comment: Sadly, the OS X version of xargs doesn't have the `-d` option, but you can install GNU xargs.