# redirect and tokenize stdout in bash

Tags: bash, tokenize, file-descriptor

I would like to find a way to redirect bash's stdout to a command that accepts strings, such as `espeak`. I originally thought to use `coproc`, but that will only work if bash sends an EOF every now and then (hopefully at good times like newlines). How can I tokenize the stdout (which is stream I/O) of an interactive process into a series of strings? It feels like something `expect` could handle, but it also feels like the question could equivalently be stated, "How do I write an interactive shell?"

Comment: Pipe it to `xargs -n 1 espeak`?

Comment: I wish this was an answer instead of a comment, because I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a line at a time being sent to `espeak` you can pipe the output to `xargs` or read it with the shell.

```
command | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 espeak
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777573/258523) and the comments for why these arguments and not others, though those concerns don't really apply here)

or

```
command | while IFS= read -r line; do espeak "$line"; done
```